# Algorithm to group repetitions in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, compression

Given a sequence of numbers, for example: `1, 2, 1, 2`.
Is there any well-known algorithm to detect repetitions and group them together such that the resulting sequence will have the shortest possible size ?

For example, for the previous sequence the result would be `(1, 2)x2`.

More examples:

```
Input: 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2
Output: ((1)x3, 2)x2

Input: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
Output: (1, 2)x3

Input: 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2
Output: (1)x2, (1, 2)x2
```

EDIT:
The length of the result (e.g. `(1, 2)x2` ) does not include any side information regarding the grouping and repetition (i.e. ignore `(),x` and the number after `x`).

For example, the length of `(1, 2)x2` is actually 2.
The length of `((1)x3, 2)x2` is still 2, since we consider only the number of elements that belongs to the original sequence (in this case 1 and 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dynamic programming method. Let's define `n` as length input sequence and `DP[i][j]` as the minimum possible length into which the substring will be compressed begin with the index `i` and ending in the index `j`. Then there are two cases:

- consistently glue: `DP[i][j] = min(DP[i][k] + DP[k + 1][j])` for all `k` from `i` to `j - 1`;
- repetitions: `DP[i][j] = min(DP[i][k])` for all such `k` which are divide a substring `i..j` into identical substrings length `k - i + 1`. I think the minimum will be in the lowest possible value of `k`.

Of the two options, choose the minimum. The string itself can also be restored (it can be stored additionally and also recalculated). Initial data `DP[i][i] = 1` for all `i` from 1 to `n`. The answer is in `DP[1][n]` (if use 1-index arrays).

Comment: Thanks, using dynamic programming is indeed a good approach. I think your answer can be simplified a bit (see last question edit).